# How to correctly send and receive messages with RabbitMQ (message gets sent but not handled ?)

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, microservices, spring-rabbit

I set up RabitMQ in a microservices environment. I have a config file as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange restaurantScoreExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange("restaurant-score-exchange");
    }
}
```

The Producer is set up like this:

```
@Component
@Import(RabbitMQConfig.class)
public class RabbitMQMessageProducer {

    private final AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public RabbitMQMessageProducer(AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }

    public void sendUpdateMessage(Long restaurantId, String message) {
        // Send the message with a routing key indicating the restaurant ID
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("restaurant-score-exchange", restaurantId.toString(), message);
    }
}
```

The controller that calls on the producer looks like this:

```
@Autowired
private final RabbitMQMessageProducer rabbitMQMessageProducer;

void randomMethod() {
    ...
    rabbitMQMessageProducer.sendUpdateMessage(newUser.getFavoriteRestaurantId(), "newUser");
    ...
}
```

The receiver (which is in another microservice) has the same config class and looks like this:

```
@Component
@Import(RabbitMQConfig.class)
public class RabbitMQMessageReceiver {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public RabbitMQMessageReceiver(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "restaurant-score-exchange")
    public void handleMessage(String message) {
        try {
            JsonNode messageJson = objectMapper.readTree(message);

            Long restaurantId = messageJson.get("restaurantId").asLong();

            // Implement the logic to update the score for the respective restaurant
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error handling message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first time playing around with message producers. The message is sent but it does not seem to get handled as I put a breakpoint in it and that does not get triggered.

I've been reading and trying to fix the issue but to no success. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can't consume from an exchange; you have to consume from a queue; declare  a queue and bind it to the exchange with a routing key.

A `DirectExchange` will need a binding for each `restaurantId`. With a `TopicExchange`, you can bind with a single routing key `#` which is a wildcard for "all".

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#binding

```java
Binding b = BindingBuilder.bind(someQueue).to(someTopicExchange).with("#");
```

See the RabbitMQ tutorials to understand different exchange types.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

There are Spring AMQP versions of the tutorials there.

Comment: I thought this was taking care of the queue: `@RabbitListener(queues = "restaurant-score-exchange")`

Comment: No; you need to declare the `Queue` and `Binding` beans.